# Django form not working for ManyToMany (auth.users)

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a `Debt` model using Django. It has a `debtors` field which link a debt to many users.

It behaves the way I want through Django's administration panel, but I can't get it to work using a django form. I can create debts but the the debtors field is emptying, despite the browser showing an accurate list of users to choose from.

What's even more surprising is that I thought that using `blank=False` in the model definition shouldn't allow that.

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Debt(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='author')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    debtors = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', blank=False)
    invoice = models.FileField(blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Debt

class NewDebtForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Debt
        fields = ('name', 'amount', 'invoice', 'created_date', 'debtors')
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Debt
from .forms import NewDebtForm

def debt_list(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewDebtForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            debt = form.save(commit=False)
            debt.author = request.user
            debt.save()
    debts = Debt.objects.order_by('created_date')
    form = NewDebtForm()
    return render(request, 'debt_share/debt_list.html',
                  {'debts': debts,
                   'form': form})
```

**debt_list.html**:

```
{% extends 'debt_share/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for debt in debts %}
        <h1>{{ debt.name }}</h1>
        <h2>payé par {{ debt.author }}</h2>
        <h2>{{ debt.amount }} {{ debt.invoice }}</h2>
        <p>
            Concerne
            {% for user in debt.debtors.all %}
                {{ user }}
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}

    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Okay, didn't know this save_m2m existed but it looks like the same issue. I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ModelForms` for many-to-many relationships, and use `form.save(commit=False)`, you have to also call `form.save_m2m()`. Many-to-many relationships have to be saved in a second step, after the original object has been created; otherwise, its ID would not be known.

For more details, refer to the explanation in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method